# Есть ли способы вызова функций WordPress без использования вызова WP-load.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

мы в плагине для *вордпресса* написали вот так

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

о моем файле *WordPress* админ говорит, что я не могу использовать этот код в моем плагине, потому что *URI* из `WP-load.php` может измениться.

Я не могу найти способ, как я могу использовать *WordPress*-функцию в моем файле без использования `WP-load.php`. Можете ли вы объяснить мне, как я могу написать свой код?

**Обновление**

Говорят, что надо написать так:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','myscript');
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var plugin_option= <?php echo json_encode(get_option('plugin_option')); ?>;
</script>
<?php
}
wp_enqueue_script('myscript','...myscript.js',...);
```

**Обновление 2**

Код из нашего плагина.

```
 require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 header('location:' . admin_url() .'admin.php?page=JunaPoll/admin.php');    

 global $wpdb;      

 $table_name  =  $wpdb->prefix . "JunaPoll_Questions";
 $table_name2 =  $wpdb->prefix . "JunaPoll_Answers";
 $table_name3 =  $wpdb->prefix . "JunaPoll_Results";
 $table_name4 =  $wpdb->prefix . "JunaPoll_Settings";       

 $question=stripslashes($_POST["question"]);

 $k=$_POST['AnswersCount'];

 $image=$_POST["img_name"];
```

Comment: Он уже подгружен в момент исполнения плагина. Если вы запрашиваете файл напрямую, то не делайте так.

Comment: но когда удаляю уже не работает

Comment: Не работает что именно? В каком окружении? *Если вы запрашиваете файл напрямую, то не делайте так.*

Comment: Написать **чтобы что**? Тут уже примерно три-четыре килобайта текста изведено, но вы так и не объяснили, что делаете.

Comment: я ничем вам не могу помочь, пока вы не объясните, что делаете.

Comment: Я не могу найти способ, как я могу использовать WordPress-функцию в моем файле без использования require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

Comment: А делаете-то что? Как код вызывается?

Comment: мы пишем полл-плагин для вордпресса  и в одном из наших файлов мы вызываем wp-load.php , но это не правильно

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, файл плагина вызывается напрямую (`/wp-content/plugins/superplugin/file.php`), что, конечно, вызывает его вне необходимого контекста. WordPress представляет довольно спорный, но работающий интерфейс для вызова произвольных функций плагина [через события](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', function () {
    // произвольный код
});
```

подобный коллбек будет вызван при запросе `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` уже в контексте WP.

Тем не менее, если, наконец, прояснится контекст, можно будет сказать что-нибудь более подробное.